# PYTHON - Find a number preceded by specific string

Tags: python, python-re

I have a text, where I want to find numbers (could be any number), preceded by specific word. (for example "your debt is 100 dollars)

I want to find a way to find "is 100".

I have already found the way to find a number followed by specific word, but I couldn't manage to do the toher way.

EX:(100 dollars)

```
import re
text="Your gift is 100 dollars"
print(re.findall(r'\b\d+\s*dollars[s]?\b', text))
['100 dollars']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following matches any number that comes after the word "is" and only returns the number:

```py
print(re.findall(r'\bis\s+(\d+)\b', text))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `split` and a comprehension:

```
>>> text = "your debt is 100 dollars"
>>> [f"{w} {n}" for w, n in zip(text.split(), text.split()[1:]) if w == "is" and n.isdecimal()]
['is 100']
```

i.e. "give me sequential pairs of words from `text` where the first word is `is` and the second word is a number".

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

text = "your debt is 100 dollars"
print(re.findall(r'is\s*\d+', text))
```

In this regex, \s* matches zero or more whitespace characters and \d+ matches one or more digits.